# How to convert java.sql.Timestamp to java.util.UUID?

Tags: java, cassandra

In cassandra, one of my column type is timeuuid whose java type equivalent as per [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/1.0/java-driver/reference/javaClass2Cql3Datatypes_r.html) is java.util.UUID

I have my input time as java.sql.Timestamp and in order to set it in entity class, I want to convert **java.sql.Timestamp -> java.util.UUID**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the documentation you mentioned refers to a very old version of the DataStax Java driver, you should upgrade to [version 3.0.0](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/).

That said, the DataStax Java driver comes with an utility class, `com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs`. It has three useful methods for dealing with time-based UUIDs:

1. `timeBased()`; creates a new time-based UUID for the current timestamp; timestamps generated by this method are suitable to be inserted in Cassandra as `timeuuid` values.
2. `startOf(long)` and `endOf(long)`: these methods provide respectively the lowest and highest possible UUIDs for a given timestamp. They are suitable mainly for querying a range of `timeuuid` values.

In your case however, it looks like you are migrating data from an RDBMS with fixed timestamps. I suggest that you consistently use `startOf(long)` to migrate your data:

```
java.sql.Timestamp tp = ...;
UUID uuid = UUIDs.startOf(tp.getTime());
```

In any case do not attempt to create such UUIDs manually, as the way Cassandra sorts `timeuuid` values is not compatible with `UUID.comapreTo()`.

Comment: I am not using DAta Stax driver, I am using thrift client, what Can I do in this case ?

Comment: In this case, place the DataStax driver jar in your classpath to use the `UUIDs` class.

Comment: @VinodJayachandran you should really consider using a newer driver.  Thrift RPC is disabled by default as of Cassandra 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/valid_literal_r.html

> timeuuid
>
> Uses the time in 100 nanosecond intervals since 00:00:00.00 UTC (60 bits), a clock sequence number for prevention of duplicates (14 bits), plus the IEEE 801 MAC address (48 bits) to generate a unique identifier. For example: d2177dd0-eaa2-11de-a572-001b779c76e3

So, a `timeuuid` includes more than just a timestamp, meaning that you could potentially generate *some* UUID from a `java.sql.Timestamp`, but it will not match any `timeuuid` in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a java.util.UUID using java.sql.Timestamp as a seed.

However, it is not a conversion since every time you generate a new UUID, it will be different.